# JavaScripts Not Working When Views Are Displayed - Rails 4 Ruby 2

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating new versions of my Rails 3.2.13 applications using Rails 4.0.0 and Ruby 2.0.0.  I am using the latest version of Michael Hartl's [Ruby On Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org) as a guide.  I am not familiar with some of the gems being used such as Turbolinks.

I have several websites that have JavaScript in the views as well as in application.html.erb.  There are times where the scripts work when a view is first displayed.  Other times the page will display with no scripts executed.  When this happens I refresh the page and all the scripts work.  This also happens from time to time with the 'new' Twitter widgets and widgets for the Weather Channel.

Here is what I have in application.html.erb:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all",
                                            "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

I have not changed any other code in my views.  When I run the Rails 3 version my scripts execute when the views are initially displayed.  However when I run the Rails 4 version I have to refresh most pages with scripts before they execute.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been looking for answers to this on the web but right before I posted this question I decided to check again.  I finally found a post that stated that it appears there are conflicts with using Turbolinks and JavaScript at times.  The suggested solution was to not require turbolinks in application.js.

```
//= require turbolinks
```

When I deleted that statement from application.js my scripts worked like they had in the Rails 3 version of my application.